# What archive manger to use instead of file-roller (now GNOME Archive Manager)?

Tags: ssh, archive, rar, file-roller

I have beating my head around this, until I realised you can't use file-roller in the terminal.
I use ssh to get into my server and now I wonder what other archive manager can I use simply from the terminal? what I am looking for is an archive manager that supports as many formats (or at least the most used ones like 7zip, rar,...) as file-roller.

Comment: Is this a GUI app?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to compress/decompress? There are many, many single-format compression applications available to the shell.

Comment: Yes i know there is a lot of different single-format tools but what i am looking for is a universal tool for most of the common formats that i can operate from the terminal.

Comment: File-roller is just a graphical front-end. It uses other command line tools to do the job. I think there isn't an "universal" tool but command line 7zip for Linux comes close.

Comment: Ok did not know that. Tanx i will try 7zip.

Answer (score 0):

```
apt install unar -y
```

I believe you will be satisfied.